# Getting readable error on python while using grid function

Tags: python, web2py

recently moved from .net to python getting some readable error while multiplying two columns in SQLForm.Grid.  The error is
`<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> grid() got an unexpected keyword argument 'readable'`

Please see the code and provide some solution

```
form = SQLFORM.grid(db.multiple,fields=[db.multiple.a1, db.multiple.b1,db.multiple.a1*db.multiple.a1],user_signature=False)
    return dict(form=form)
```

Comment: It may be helpful to tell us what the error message says.

Comment: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'> grid() got an unexpected keyword argument 'readable'

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback, not just the last line?  I've also had a look at the [source code for SQLFORM](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/sqlhtml.py) and I can't see how the error you describe could be triggered by the line of code above.  So I can only conclude that you are mistaken about where the problem actually is.  *Please double-check where the error is in your code.*  Use the line-numbers in the tracebacks to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the error you are reporting is coming from that code (you are not passing a "readable" argument to `.grid()`). However, there is an error in your code. The "fields" argument must be a list of `Field` objects, but you have included `db.multiple.a1*db.multiple.a1` in the list, which is an `Expression` object and not allowed. If you want to display a column that is the product of two fields in the table, you can create a virtual field or use the "links" argument to create an additional column.